# How to sneak dynamic data into react state from apollo query without breaking react's rules

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo

My goal is to run the apollo query hook (`useDataAboutThing`), get the part of the `data` object I need, and get that resulting data into `event` with `setEvent`. Every attempt I try at solving this, I violate the law of hooks or create a feedback loop. This seems like it should be easy which probably means I have a flawed understanding of React that needs to be corrected.

```
type ComponentProps = {
  id: number;
}

const Component = ({ id }: ComponentProps) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useDataAboutThing({
    variables: {
       id: id,
    },
  });

  const [event, setEvent] = React.useState([]);
  
  // without checking these, data is undefined
  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (error) return <div>Error!</div>;

  const dataInformation = data.information;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setEvent(dataInformation)
  }, []) // Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

  return (
    ...
  );
```

Comment: Try adding `data` as useEffect dependency

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` without dependency is executed when the function is called,

1. you should make it dependent on `data`.
2. Check if the expected data exists in data
3. assign it to the state.

```
type ComponentProps = {
  id: number;
}

const Component = ({ id }: ComponentProps) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useDataAboutThing({
    variables: {
       id: id,
    },
  });

  const [event, setEvent] = React.useState([]);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (error) return <div>Error!</div>;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(data.information) setEvent(dataInformation)
  }, [data]) // Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

  return (
    ...
  );
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution but I think my initial question was poorly presented. The problem I have is I can't use `useEffect` before my if statements that check on `error` and `loading` for values, it doesn't add the data to state because at that point `data` is undefined. if I try to use `useEffect` the way I posted it (after those two conditional statements) I violate the law of hooks. I've edited my initial question hoping to make my issue clearer.

Comment: if this is your case then you can do without useEffect and use the condition this condition outside
```
if(data.information) setEvent(dataInformation)
``

Comment: I tried this too but when I do this, it throws `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Answer (score 0):

**Now first:** *useEffect* cannot be called **conditionally** (after if condition) so before your check whether it's loading or having errors you have to locate the *useEffect* .
**second:** since the logic in your *useEffect* happens based on the data you have to include it inside array's dependencies .

```
type ComponentProps = {
  id: number;
}

const Component = ({ id }: ComponentProps) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useDataAboutThing({
    variables: {
       id: id,
    },
  });

  const [event, setEvent] = React.useState([]);

      React.useEffect(() => {
       if (data?.information) {
          setEvent(data.information)
       }
      }, [data]);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (error) return <div>Error!</div>;

  return (
    ...
  );
```